# Get $scope from one controller to modal controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, bootstrap-modal

I have a page that uses ctrlone, I want to copy the whole $scope variable to ctrltwo which is a modal window.

In ctrlone I am opening the modal like this

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'Modal.html',
        windowClass: 'ModalWidth',
        $scope: function() {
            var scope = $scope;
}(),
controller: "ctrltwo" });
```

What I have for ctrltwo is

```
.controller('ctrltwo', ["$scope", "$modal","itTransport", function ($scope, $modal,transport) {
var test = $scope;
}])
```

Problem is $scope doesnt seem to be copying over. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the whole $scope like this

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: 'MyModalCtrl',
    scope: $scope
});
```

However, if you don't actually need the whole object, I recommend to use `resolve` instead to pass parameters.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: 'MyModalCtrl',
    resolve: {
        variableToPass: function () {
            return $scope.items;
        }
    }
});
```

Then you define your modal controller like this

```
myApp.controller('MyModalCtrl', ['$scope', $modalInstance'', 'variableToPass', function($scope, $modalInstance, variableToPass) {
    ...
}]);
```

Comment: if someone is using `$mdDialog` then the function in `resolve` must return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
$scope: function() {
   var scope = $scope;
}()
```

...is equivalent to:

```
$scope: undefined
```

That's because when a javascript function does not have a return statement, the function returns undefined by default.

In addition, `$modal.open()` does not have an option named `$scope`.  See a description of the available options for `$modal.open()` in the `Modal section` here:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/